# Polymer 2.0 upload to GitHub-Pages

Tags: github, polymer, github-pages, polymer-2.x

I have problem with uploading my Polymer component into gh pages.

I'm try this from tutorial:

```
    # git clone the Polymer tools repository somewhere outside of your 
# element project
git clone git://github.com/Polymer/tools.git

# Create a temporary directory for publishing your element and cd into it
mkdir temp && cd temp

# Run the gp.sh script. This will allow you to push a demo-friendly
# version of your page and its dependencies to a GitHub pages branch
# of your repository (gh-pages). Below, we pass in a GitHub username
# and the repo name for our element
../tools/bin/gp.sh <username> <test-element>

# Finally, clean-up your temporary directory as you no longer require it
cd ..
rm -rf temp
```

But it's not working.
In terminal I have this errors:[image]

There is something I'm, missing?

Comment: u sure you have a repository under "https://github.com/maciejwojcik/drop-down-box"? nothing public I can see?
I guess pages will work only for public repositories...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

For the script to run as intended, you need to add your public ssh key to your github project. Settings -> Deploy keys -> Add deploy Key.

Alternatively, you can manually execute the steps in gp.sh that involve pulling from and pushing to github.

If you don't feel like splitting up the script, try running the commands manually, that should work. The only multi-line command in the script is this one:

```
echo "{
  \"directory\": \"components\"
}
" > .bowerrc
```

Good luck.